# Remove key from mixed array and reindex

Tags: php, arrays, postgresql, reindex, array-key

I am new to postgresql with php. I get below array using **pg_fetch_array()** function.

```
Array
(
    [0] => 
    [name] => 
    [1] => 1
    [status] => 1
    [2] => C2005
    [code] => C2005
)
```

after removing index `1` and value of key `status`, i have to reindex this array so that expected output should become like:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 
    [name] => 
    [1] => C2005
    [code] => C2005
)
```

I tried

```
unset($row[1]);
unset($row['status'];
$foo = array_values($row);
echo "<pre>";
print_r($foo)
echo "</pre>";
```

and got output

```
Array
(
    [0] => 
    [name] => 
    [2] => C2005
    [code] => C2005
)
```

How the numeric index can be re-indexed after removing particular keys from the array?

Comment: Use `pg_fetch_assoc()` instead of `pg_fetch_array()` then you wont get the numerically indexed columns, it will return only the named columns

Comment: Alternatively use `pg_fetch_array($result, NULL, PGSQL_ASSOC);` to just get the associative array

Comment: why you don't only select the `name, code` in your select statement ?

Comment: and how could `array_values` returns with associated array  ? it **must** returns with numeric array

Comment: As this is an existing code of live application, so i can not make any further changes. the field status is injected in the main query for  some reason but later on it needs to be removed from the result. Is there any way we can re-index the array after removing particular key values?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can filter the array by their key. **[Live demo](https://eval.in/778358)**.

```
unset($array['status']);
$number_keys = array_values(array_filter($array, function($k){return is_int($k) && $k != 1;}, ARRAY_FILTER_USE_KEY));
$nonnumber_keys = array_filter($array, function($k){return is_string($k);}, ARRAY_FILTER_USE_KEY);
$result = array_merge($number_keys, $nonnumber_keys);
```

Comment: it did not work. i printed $result after replacing $array in your example with my array variable

Comment: It worked !! Thanks for providing live demo. I observed that i was missing something. But now your solution is working for me.